# angularjs add simple jquery event listener

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Ok, I must be missing something simple.  I am making an app with angular and I want to implement some google analytics form watching code, so I want something like

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() { 
     $(':input').blur(function () {
        if($(this).val().length > 0) {
          _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'INSERT FORM NAME HERE', 'completed',   $(this).attr('name')]);
        } 
        else {
           _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'INSERT FORM NAME HERE', 'skipped', $(this).attr('name')]);
     });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

see [here](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2012/11/13/track-form-abandonment-google-analytics/#sr=g&m=o&cp=or&ct=-tmc&st=%28opu%20qspwjefe%29&ts=1389906250)

I was hoping to use something simple like that instead of a directive on every single form input.  That would keep this in one place for removal or whatever later on.

This code, however, never fires.  I am using ng-includes for parts of the form, so it sounds to me like the traditional document.ready way of attaching a jquery event listener will no longer work because it fires before those parts are included.

I also tried a directive on the top level form element like so:

```
angular.module('ngPayment2App')
 .directive('formTracker', function () {
   return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.find(':input').on('blur',function(){
        console.log('finally!')
      })
    }
  };
});
```

'finally' never shows.

Anybody got any ideas.  I know I am making a noob mistake, I just don't know what it is yet....

Comment: From docs: *find() - Limited to lookups by tag name* (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element)

Answer (score 0):

Your directive (the way it's currently written) will only work if you include jQuery in your app.

<kbd>[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gavinfoley/7gW6Q/)</kbd>

This is because AngularJS only comes with [jQuery lite](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element) so `find()` only accepts elements e.g. `input, p, div` so pseudo class selectors (like what you're using with `:input`) won't work without jQuery included in your app.
This is done by adding a script reference to jQuery before your AngularJS reference. 
Also jqLite's `on()` function doesn't support event data. You should be able to use `bind()` instead (assuming you aren't dynamically loading your content).

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {})
.directive('formTracker', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            // Requires jQuery
            element.on('blur', ':input', function () {
                console.log('finally!');
            });

            // Timeout added for display purpose only
            // Wait 3 seconds and add a new HTML input
            $timeout(function(){
                element.append('<br><span>Element added after DOM has finished rendering</span><br><input id="dynamic-element" name="dynamic-elemen" type="text">');
            }, 3000);

        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I do in fact import jQuery before angular, so that's not it.  I think that it is the DOM not being ready... If I add the jquery call inside a timeout for 2 seconds, everything works.

Comment: @jessehensold I've updated the JSFiddle; You just need to update the `on()` func to something like `element.on('blur', ':input', function () { console.log('finally!'); });` which will attach the `blur` event to all items that match the following selector, regardless of when they're added to the DOM (i.e. after DOM has finished loading).